# Open large geotif file

Tags: python, raster, ram, geopandas, geotiff

I have very large geotif file. But I can not open it in colabs. RAM is not enough. So all the time I run it began crash. can come one help me with this?

````
import numpy as np
from rasterio.plot import show
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

# Data dir
data_dir = "data"

# Filepath
fp = os.path.join(data_dir, "/content/drive/MyDrive/LINEasia/test2.tif")

# Open the raster file in read mode
raster = rasterio.open(fp)

# Read NIR channel (channel number 4)
nir = raster.read(1)

# Calculate some stats to check the data
#print(red.mean())
print(nir.mean())
print(type(nir))

# Visualize
show(nir, cmap='terrain')
}```

uncompressed file size around 3GB.
````

Comment: Well, probably the "easiest" way would be to add some RAM? What is the size of RAM that you have? Can you exit some other programs to free up some more memory space?

Answer (score 3):

You can work on smaller portions more like windows. Below code reads 400x400 window from (0, 0) point.

```
with rasterio.open('/content/drive/MyDrive/LINEasia/test2.tif') as f:
    w = f.read(1, window=Window(0, 0, 400, 400))
```

Comment: yes we can do but the problem is it is a map. if we get that part some area can be loss. That is the reson

Comment: If you are trying to evaluate something from map (like nir.mean()) you can traverse multiple windows that will cover all of the map and each take partial calculations. Later on you can sum up with another calculation. If you are trying to visualize it, you can't just directly load all of the map without unloading some parts or without compression